# How can I call a javascript function upon hovering an a-frame element, using its ID?

Tags: javascript, hover, aframe, mouseenter, queryselector

I have been calling javascript functions on mouseenter, like this:

```js
document.querySelector('a-cylinder').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  alert("This is a cylinder.");
})

document.querySelector('a-box').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  alert("This is a box.");
})

document.querySelector('testBox').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  alert("This is a box, targeted with an ID");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@3.0.3/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>

<a-scene>
  <a-camera camera look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .hoverable"></a-camera>
  <a-box class="hoverable" position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-box id="testBox" class="hoverable" position="0 0.8 -4" rotation="0 45 0" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-box>
  <a-cylinder class="hoverable" position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

It works for the cylinder, and for the first box (the one that comes first in the HTML). However, I cannot specify which box I want to hover on to call the function if, instead of using `querySelector('a-box')` I use `querySelector('elementID')`.

Comment: @SMAKSS Both answers show me what I was doing wrong, and fixed my problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind, **`querySelector` will always return the first matched element**, so **in order to get all the boxes, you should use `querySelectorAll`** instead. Also, **for selecting `id` you should refer it by `#` keyword**.

There are multiple ways to overcome this situation, for **selecting each specific element in your DOM you can simply assign a unique `id` to each of them and then refer to them by `document.getElementById`**. So let's find out how it works exactly, for instance, let's say you assign a unique `id` to your second box like this:

```html
<a-box id="testBox" class="hoverable" position="0 0.8 -4" rotation="0 45 0" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-box>
```

For referring to such an element you can either do it with `getElementById` or `querySelector` just like this:

```js
document.getElementById('#testBox').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  alert("This is a box, targeted with an ID");
})

// or

document.querySelector('#testBox').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  alert("This is a box, targeted with an ID");
})
```

**NOTE:** You should always consider using `#` for selecting items by `id` and `.` for selecting items by `class`.

But if you got a situation when the elements are too much and **you want to avoid using the unique `id` for each of them you can do this by `querySelectorAll`** and then iterate through them and add an event to each element. For more info, you can read [this](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#with-queryselectorall).

I will just fix your current code, so your code should be something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('a-cylinder').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  alert("This is a cylinder.");
})

document.querySelector('a-box').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  alert("This is a box.");
})

document.querySelector('#testBox').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
  alert("This is a box, targeted with an ID");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@3.0.3/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>

<a-scene>
  <a-camera camera look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .hoverable"></a-camera>
  <a-box class="hoverable" position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-box id="testBox" class="hoverable" position="0 0.8 -4" rotation="0 45 0" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-box>
  <a-cylinder class="hoverable" position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to an item by class, use queryElementsByClassName. This can return multiple items.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

if you want to refer to item by its ID, use getElementById. If an item does not have an ID, then you have to use querySelector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

querySelector can query for tag, class, or ID, if you specify # for ID and . for class, like .hoverable or #testbox. However, it will only return one item.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

If you want more than one, use querySelectorAll